# Usage of binary semaphore - not working correctly (Selling tickets)

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore, atomic

I'm trying to implement a simple problem where i have a global variable to sell tickets. 
I spawn 3 threads to sell 10 tickets and this i'm doing using a binary semaphore.

```
private static int noOfTickets =10;
private static boolean soldAll = false;
private static Random r = new Random(10);

/************ MAIN **************/
public static void main(String[] arg){
    // spawn 10 threads to see a tickets

    for(int i =0; i<3; i++){
        Thread t = new Thread(new sellRunnable());
        t.setName("Me_"+i);
        t.start();
    }
}
/************ MAIN **************/


public static void sell() throws InterruptedException{
    Semaphore b = new Semaphore(1);
    int numOfTicketsSoldByThisThread = 0;
    while(!soldAll){

        addRandomDelay(1000, 100);

        b.acquire();
        if(noOfTickets>0){
            Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
            numOfTicketsSoldByThisThread++;
            noOfTickets--;
            System.out.println("I "+t.getName()+" sold "+numOfTicketsSoldByThisThread+"ticket. tickets left are "+noOfTickets);


        }else{
            soldAll = true;
            System.out.println(" sold all tickets");
        }
        b.release();
    }// end of while


}

public static class sellRunnable implements Runnable{

    public void run() {
        try {
            sell();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

When i run this code, i'm not getting the correct output, at some point of time
I get this

- I Me_2 sold 1ticket. tickets left are 7
- I Me_1 sold 1ticket. tickets left are 7

Notice, how two threads are printing out that the tickets left is 7?. That can't be right? I know that noOfTicketsLeft-- is NOT an atomic operation, but it's inside the semaphore. So,it should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the same Semaphore instance for all three threads.  As it stands, they're all pointing to different semaphores, so they don't actually lock each other out.

BTW, even though this looks like it might just be for quick practice, you really should get out of the habit of using static variables; declare a class, and then instantiate it and invoke it in main().  It doesn't take much more effort, and it's far cleaner.

Comment: I agree. I just removed all the static variables. Thanks for noticing my mistake!. It works now.